# When is vitamin D released from fat?

Tags: vitamin-d

I understand that vitamin D is a fat soluble vitamin, and that being overweight can adversely affect the availability of vitamin D in the body. It seems that having more fat on the body results in more removal of vitamin D from the bloodstream. If that vitamin is being stored in fat, when is it released, and is it equally effective when released? Can burning fat in the winter release vitamin D, and thus work to offset the vitamin D deficiency resulting from lack of available sunlight?

Answer (score 2):

It is already released in winter, and may help prevent very low levels that might otherwise be obtained.

> Vitamin D Stored in Fat Tissue During a 5-Year Intervention Affects Serum 25-Hydroxyvitamin D Levels the Following Year.

Martinaityte I1,2, Kamycheva E1,2, Didriksen A1, Jakobsen J3, Jorde R1,2.

Author information

Abstract

**CONTEXT**:

Vitamin D and 25-hydroxyvitamin D [25(OH)D] are stored in adipose tissue, but the clinical relevance is uncertain.

**OBJECTIVE**:

To evaluate changes in serum 25(OH)D and adipose tissue vitamin D levels after stopping vitamin Dsupplementation.

**DESIGN**:

A prospective, double-blind cohort follow-up study.

**SETTING**:

Clinical Research Unit at University Hospital of North Norway.

**PATIENTS**:

Seventy-six subjects were included after participation in a 3- to 5-year prevention of type 2 diabetes study and were administered 20,000 IU of vitamin D or placebo per week.

**INTERVENTION**:

During the 12-month follow-up period, blood samples were drawn at the beginning and after 1, 3, 6, 9, and 12 months. Fat biopsies were taken at the start and end.

**MAIN OUTCOME MEASURES**:

Changes in 25(OH)D level in serum and 25(OH)D and vitamin D levels in adipose tissue.

**RESULTS**:

Forty-one of 42 subjects who were given vitamin D and 33 of 34 subjects who were given placebo completed the study. At the inclusion, mean serum 25(OH)D levels were 122 and 71 nmol/L in the vitamin D and placebo groups, respectively. Serum 25(OH)D levels were significantly higher in the vitamin D group than in the placebo group throughout and were 84.5 and 73.1 nmol/L, respectively, after 12 months. In the vitamin D group, adipose tissue vitamin D levels decreased by 52% over 12 months.

**CONCLUSION**:

Vitamin D and 25(OH)D stored in adipose tissue after 3 to 5 years of vitamin D supplementation may have a clinically relevant effect on serum 25(OH)D level the following year.

Comment: Nice answer except one thing. I'm sure you know what it is.

Comment: you want the doi as well?

Comment: Sorry, I commented too quickly. I was looking for a supporting source and failed to notice that your entire post IS a supporting source.